# UTC date from different daylight savings adjusted for current timezone

Tags: timezone, momentjs, utc, dst, timezone-offset

I have dates saved in mongodb in UTC format, e.g. "2016-01-28T00:00:00.000Z". In the client I am using moment.js to format the date. However, when I created a moment of this particular date, daylight savings comes into play:

`>moment("2016-01-28T00:00:00.000Z").format()`

> "2016-01-27T19:00:00-05:00"

If I use moment's timezone to adjust this time, it will not work because the offset is -4 at the moment, not -5. What is the correct way to adjust this time, such that instead of 1/27/16, I get 1/28/16, which is what i want. At the moment, one solution I though of what to get the `.utcOffset` in minutes and add this to the moment of my time:

`moment("2016-01-28T00:00:00.000Z").add(
-moment("2016-01-28T00:00:00.000Z").utcOffset(),'minutes').format()`

> "2016-01-28T00:00:00-05:00"

However, I am not sure if this is the best way of doing this.

Comment: You have an offset in your input (`Z`, which is for UTC, and equivalent to `+00:00`).  See the answer in the dup post to understand how to use the `parseZone` function to retain it, or the `utc` function to use UTC exclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the specification for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators), specifically surrounding the timezone designators.

The "Z" at the end of the formatted input string designates the number as being in the UTC timezone. The `moment` library takes the UTC date and automatically converts it to the local timezone, which in your case means subtracting a few hours off.

If you take the "Z" off, then `moment` will interpret it as an "unspecified" time zone, and will not add or subtract any time from the given datetime. So note:

```
> moment("2016-01-28T00:00:00.000Z").format()
< "2016-01-27T19:00:00-05:00"
> moment("2016-01-28T00:00:00.000").format()
< "2016-01-28T00:00:00-05:00"
```

After removing the "Z", `moment` will still format the new date with `-05:00` as the timezone designator, but won't modify the datetime.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a good idea.  While it may give the same *local time* value, you've actually changed the intent of the timestamp, putting it at a different moment in time.  See the answer in the dup link for the correct approach.